# Logic App to Queue - SSL connection could not be established

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

We have a Logic App trying to access the Storage Account Queue, secured by a private endpoint. Both resources are in the same SNET. We have configured our Managed Identities correctly and given `Storage Queue Data Contributor` access to the storage account. When trying to put a message in the queue, we are getting the error:

> SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

We checked [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#tlsssl-certificate-authentication) but are not aware of what certificate they are talking about. Please check the error screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we need to whitelist the IP addresses in our company's firewall. However, there is a catch. According to [this community post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/access-azure-blob-using-logic-app/ba-p/1451573), we required our logic app and storage accounts in different regions. Since the move was not possible, we changed all our connectors to built-in connectors instead of Azure public connectors. Changing to the built-in connectors came with its own challenges, but we were able to achieve our purpose.